# Склонение с родовым словом

Tags: склонение

Как склонять (или вообще не склонять) слово ИСЛАМ в след. случаях?
Мы изучаем религию ислам(а).
Значение религии ислам(а) определяется...
Они пришли к религии ислам(у,а).
Они аргументируют это религией ислам(ом,а).
Они услышали о религии ислам(е,а).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что в сочетании ***религия ислам*** название "ислам" не склоняется. Более того, родовое слово в таких случаях практически не используется, и это касается не только ислама, но и, к примеру, православия. **Мы не говорим:** я много читал о религии исламе и о религии православии, **но говорим**: я много читал об исламе и о  православии.

Можно посмотреть дискуссию на эту тему http://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/utochnenie-voprosa-ob-islame

В то же время **в некоторых случаях эти сочетания все-таки употребляются**, но не в косвенных падежах, например:

**Традиционные религии Ислам и Православие** рассматриваются в государствах Средней Азии как духовная опора общества. [митрополит Владимир (Иким). ...А друзей искать на Востоке (2001)]

...противопоставление религиозных и национальных начал в человеке ― искусственная проблема, так как Всевышний создал **и религию Ислам**, и народы, чья обязанность перед Аллахом ― быть живыми носителями Его законов ... [Хож-Ахмед Нухаев.  // «Звезда», 2002]

Comment: А в общем случае склоняется ли существительное после родового слова? Из рыбы карп или из рыбы карпа? И т. п.

Comment: Я задал отдельный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444738/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-2