# Склонение с родовым словом (2)

Tags: склонение

Как понять, когда название, стоящее после родового слова, склоняется?  Тут работают правила или традиция?

О породе джек-рассел-терьер, но о городе Москве. О рыбе карп или о рыбе карпе (еще сомнительней "из рыбы карпа")? О профессии художник или о профессии художника (здесь уже не приложение превратилось в дополнение)? И т. п.

Answer (score 1):

О приложениях - географических названиях можно прочитать, например, в розенталевском справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию (параграф 197). (Мне там очень не нравится "у реки Днепра", а это как раз он считает правильным, правда, пример там другой: "на реке Днепре", что выглядит более приемлемо).

Теперь про художника. Есть книжка Г. Товстоногова "О профессии режиссера". Но это не совсем то, это же не приложение. Вот "о рыбе карпе" - здесь приложение. Примера найти не могу.

Comment: Хотелось бы знать, существует ли общий подход или нужно искать ответ для каждого конкретного случая отдельно.